# How can I convert strings like "\u5c0f\u738b\u5b50\u003a\u6c49\u6cd5\u82f1\u5bf9\u7167" to Chinese characters

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am now working on a small tool to request and decode a webpage, on which the Chinese characters are stored as string like

```
\u5c0f\u738b\u5b50\u003a\u6c49\u6cd5\u82f1\u5bf9\u7167
```

in the source code, something of unicode. I want to convert it to Chinese characters.

I can make it through this website http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/. But How can I make it  using python?

Comment: Possibly related: [How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are Unicode codepoints *already*. They represent Chinese characters, but using escape codes that are easier on the developer:

```
>>> print u'\u5c0f\u738b\u5b50\u003a\u6c49\u6cd5\u82f1\u5bf9\u7167'
小王子:汉法英对照
```

You do not have to do *anything* to convert those; the `\uxxxx` escape form is simply another way to express the same codepoint. See [String Literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> `\uxxxx`
>    Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx (Unicode only)
>   `\Uxxxxxxxx`
>   Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx (Unicode only)

Python interprets those escape codes when reading the source code to construct the unicode value.

If the source of the data is not from Python source code but from the web, you have JSON data instead, which uses the same escape format:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.loads('"\u5c0f\u738b\u5b50\u003a\u6c49\u6cd5\u82f1\u5bf9\u7167"')
小王子:汉法英对照
```

Note that the value then needs to be part of a larger string, one that *at least* includes quotes to mark this a string.

Also note that the JSON string escape format differs from Python's when it comes to non-BMP (supplementary) codepoints; JSON treats those like UTF-16 does, by [creating a surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) and use two `\uxxxx` sequences for such a codepoint. In Python you'd use a `\Uhhhhhhhh` 32-bit hex value.

Comment: With python 3, you don't event need to prefix the string with u: `print("\u5c0f\u738b\u5b50\u003a\u6c49\u6cd5\u82f1\u5bf9\u7167")`

Comment: But the source code string I get from the webpage is in this format. So in the python string, the content is `\u5c0f\u738b\u5b50\u003a\u6c49\u6cd5\u82f1\u5bf9\u7167`. It is not recognized as unicode. How can it be solved?

Comment: Then you have JSON data, updating.